# How to define in Julia ReinforcementLearning.jl an action space that changes with each state?

Tags: julia, reinforcement-learning

I want to implement an environment in Julia ReinforcementLearning.jl that has continuous action space that change as a function of the state. The state is a positive integer `n <= nmax` for a given `nmax`. The action space is the n-dimensional vector space `[0, 1]^n`, that is, an action is a vector of size `n` that has elements in `[0,1]`.

What I implemented is the `RLBase.action_space(env::MyEnv)` which is essentially

```
using ReinforcementLearning
using IntervalSets # for ClosedInterval


RLBase.action_space(env::MyEnv) = Space(ClosedInterval{Float32}[0..1 for _ in 1:state(env)]) 
# state(env) is an integer between 1 and nmax.
```

I think this implementation is not complete because in the documentation of `ReinforcementLearning.jl`, it is mentioned that `legal_action_space` and `legal_action _space_mask` should be implemented when `ActionStyle` is `FULL_ACTION_SET`.

How should I implemented `legal_action_space` and `legal_action_space_mask` (is it possible to use action masking with continuous action spaces?) and should I use `ActionTransformedEnv` when defining my environment?